# Object Reference not set to an instance of an object while play sound using script in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to play and pause sound in game using script. *I have a sound manager script to load and play sound file. I try to play audio from other script.* But the error occurs saying " **Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object** " on the **other script** where I have written code to play audio.

**sound manager script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class soundManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static AudioSource au_GameStart;
    public static AudioSource au_afterStart;
    public static AudioSource au_carStart;
    public static AudioSource au_go;
    public static AudioSource au_strike;

    public static bool muteStatus;
    public static soundManager instance;
    void Start () {
        muteStatus = false;
        instance=this;
        au_GameStart = (AudioSource)gameObject.AddComponent <AudioSource>();
        au_afterStart = (AudioSource)gameObject.AddComponent <AudioSource>();
        au_carStart = (AudioSource)gameObject.AddComponent <AudioSource>();
        au_go = (AudioSource)gameObject.AddComponent <AudioSource>();
        au_strike = (AudioSource)gameObject.AddComponent <AudioSource>();

        AudioClip clip_GameStart;
        clip_GameStart = (AudioClip)Resources.Load ("SFX/game_start");
        au_GameStart.clip = clip_GameStart;
        au_GameStart.loop = false;

        AudioClip clip_AfterStart;
        clip_AfterStart = (AudioClip)Resources.Load ("SFX/after_start");
        au_afterStart.clip = clip_AfterStart;
        au_afterStart.loop = false;

        AudioClip clip_carStart;
        clip_carStart = (AudioClip)Resources.Load ("SFX/car_start");
        au_carStart.clip = clip_carStart;
        au_carStart.loop = false;

        AudioClip clip_GO;
        clip_GO = (AudioClip)Resources.Load ("SFX/go");
        au_go.clip = clip_GO;
        au_go.loop = false;

        AudioClip clip_Strike;
        clip_Strike = (AudioClip)Resources.Load ("SFX/strike");
        au_strike.clip = clip_Strike;
        au_strike.loop = true;
}
```

**other script**

```
void Start()
{
soundManager.au_GameStart.Play();
}
```

When I run unity game , it give an error in **other script** saying "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object ". *I have attached soundmanager script to gameobject named SoundManager . And SoundManager gameobject loads sound during play mode.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, do the variables for your AudioSource's need to be static? I would suggest maybe making them `public` non-static, then to create an instance of your `soundManager` in the `other script`, and access the AudioSource's through your instance variable in `other script` - that is, if the fields do not need to static. Also, maybe change the soundManager `Start` function to `Awake`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Start()` in `otherscript` is executed before `Start()` in `soundManager`.
Changing `Start()` in `soundManager` class to `Awake()` should fix the problem.

Or

If you didn't want renaming you could change [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html)

**Update:**
As Everts pointed out in his comments, doing initialization in Start() or Awake is commonly not a good practice because their execution order cannot be guaranteed unless you explicitly specify [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html). But even [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html) can lead to hard to understand code because [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html) itself is not visible in code.

So the idea is that, you create an Init() so you have full control over initialization of that object. And if in side the Init() you need to init some other objects, call Init() of them.

EDIT : When you get to a point where one class (ClassA) depends on another (ClassB), it becomes necessary that ClassA triggers ClassB.

```
public class ClassB : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MonoA monoA = null;
    public void Init(){
        this.monoA = this.gameObject.GetComponent<MonoA>();
    }
    public void GetMonoAValue(){
        if(this.monoA == null){  this.monoA = this.gameObject.GetComponent<MonoA>(); }
        return this.monoA.Value;
    }
}

public class ClassA:MonoBehaviour
{
     private void Start(){
         ClassB classB = FindObjectOfType<ClassB>();
         classB.Init();
         Value v = classB.GetMonoAValue(); 
     }
}
```

This case is fairly simple, you could directly call the GetMonoAValue since it initializes in case of null value. This was for the example and your Init method may contain more code.

Comment: Generally when one class depends on the data of another, starting to change Start for Awake and vice-versa is a wrong idea. Coz now your class on Awake may need something from another or the other way around... Solution is that the class needing data from the other calls an Init method, so you are sure. Using ScriptExecutionOrder is a solution until someone else comes along. Then he is back into "Why is this happening?!" since execution order is not explicit in code. Just create  a public Init.

Comment: Please help me to edit the answer if it is not what you are saying :)

Comment: Thanks @Loop , **I simply shift my start function code to awake function** as said by you guys. And it works fine.

Comment: Glad to be of help! But please do pay attention to the Update & Edit section. I was once doing initialization in Start() & Awake() and it caused me a lot of headache.